# How can I tell whether PFS is enabled?

Tags: ssl, https, nginx, ssl-certificate

I have kinda 2 questions.. first, **is this setting considered "secure"** ?

[image]

[image]

Second, **how do I tell whether perfect forward secrecy is enabled**?

```
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM EDH+AESGCM EECDH -RC4 EDH -CAMELLIA -SEED !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I tell whether PFS is enabled?
>
> is 128-bit SHA1 considered "secure"?

[Cryptography questions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) are pretty complex and involve numerous different factors that can affect overall security, so it is hard to say what is good or not. Moreover, it depends entirely on you and your needs.

If you are using SSL casually for a personal blog or something, then it is more than enough. If you are using it to provide a donation button for a small personal site, it is still sufficient. If you are using it for a financial website like that of a bank, then you might want to consider something a little stronger.

The US government considers AES-128 [to be good enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Security) for “TOP SECRET” level documents, but SHA1 [collisions were found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1#Attacks) as far back as 2005. Of course those were for a reduced subset of SHA1, but that is not a guarantee of indefinite security. ([No collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1#Comparison_of_SHA_functions) have been found for SHA2 yet.)

If you examine the SSL used by a variety of websites (screenshots below), aside from some interesting and curious results, you’ll notice that many tend to use RC4 for encryption, SHA1 for authentication, and RSA for key exchange. If that’s good enough for banks and governments, then it is probably good enough for most users.

> Second, how do I tell whether perfect forward secrecy is enabled?

[Lorrin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17463708/119540) and [Reid](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8938) have given thorough answers to using SSL with PFS. One thing I notice is that you have actually avoided RC4 for some reason.

You can test your server for forward-security (and other security aspects) with the [SSL Lab server-test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). (One curious note is that even the high-security sites below don’t seem to validate for forward-security. I don’t know what site the article [*SSL Labs: Deploying Forward Secrecy*](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/06/25/ssl-labs-deploying-forward-secrecy) used for their screenshot of FS working on various clients.)

---

**Figure 1**: Google’s SSL implementation

[image: Screenshot of Google site security]

**Figure 2**: PayPal’s SSL implementation

[image: Screenshot of PayPal site security]

**Figure 2**: Chase-Manhattan bank’s SSL implementation

[image: Screenshot of Chase site security]

**Figure 3**: The CIA’s SSL implementation

[image: Screenshot of CIA site security]

**Figure 2**: The FBI’s **inconsistent** SSL implementation

[image: Screenshot of FBI site security]

**Figure 2**: The DHS doesn’t use SSL at all on their homepage, despite it featuring an article about cyber-security

[image: Screenshot of DHS site security]

Answer (score 0):

You can answer both of your questions if you use any number of SSL certificate-checking sites.
For example https://sslcheck.globalsign.com and/or https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html gives you a pretty good overview of the quality of your SSL Certificate and how well your web server is configured to handle various encryption parameters. It also gives you links to helpful information on how to address any issues it detects.